# Angular Promise not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

I try to get some important things like: `companyid,employeeid` etc. with every request that a user makes. So this has to be received **before** everything else is done.

After that the user receives information based on his companyid that he sets with every request (`get/company/{companyid}`).

The problem that I have is that the response for receiving the companyid takes to long and angular already tries to make a request to (`get/company/{companyid}`) obviously there is no `companyid` yet.

I've tried to fix this whit promise but it's not working.

Here I try to receive some important information about the user(that I do with every request) :

**Service**

```
(function () {
    angular.module('employeeApp')
        .service('authenticationservice', authenticationservice);

    function authenticationservice($http,$location,authenticationFactory,$q,GLOBALS,$cookies) {

        this.validateUser = function () {
            var vm = this;
            vm.deferred = $q.defer();

            data = {"api_token": api_token};

            return $http.post(GLOBALS.url+'show/employee/' + $cookies.get('employeeid'),data)
                .success(function(response)
                {
                    vm.deferred.resolve(response);
                })
                .error(function(err,response)
                {
                    vm.deferred.reject(err);
                });

            return vm.deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})();
```

**Routes file**
(In my routes file I use the `authenticationservice` to set all important users variables.)

```
employeeAppModule.run([
        'authenticationservice',
        'constants',
        function(authenticationservice,constants) {
            authenticationservice.validateUser()
                .then(function(response)
                {
                    constants.companyid = response.result.Employee;
                    constants.role = response.result.Role;
                    constants.name = response.result.FirstName;
                    console.log('test');
                },
                function(response){
                    console.log('error');
                });

        }
    ]);
```

So the problem is that the user information is set to late and angular already goes to my homeController where he uses the companyId that is not being set yet.

Thankyou

Comment: `$http` already returns a promise which you could simply return. Why are you trying to wrap it in `$q`?

Comment: `.success` is deprecated. See docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Comment: You need to resolve the promise before returning it: vm.deferred.resolve();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your current code is `return $http.post` are having two return statement in your `validateUser` method. Which is returning `$http.get` before returning `return vm.deferred.promise;` & that why customly created promise doesn't get returned from your method. Though by removing first `return` from `$http.get` will fix your problem, I'd not suggest to go for such fix, because it is considered as bad pattern to implement.

Rather I'd say, you should utilize promise return by `$http` method, & use `.then` to return data to chain promise mechanism.

**Code**

```
function authenticationservice($http, $location, authenticationFactory, $q, GLOBALS, $cookies) {
  this.validateUser = function() {
    var vm = this;

    data = {
      "api_token": api_token
    };

    return $http.post(GLOBALS.url + 'show/employee/' + $cookies.get('employeeid'), data)
      .then(function(response) {
      var data = response.data;
      retrun data;
    }, function(err) {
      return $q.reject(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that $ http return a $ promise object you need to check that the action in the controller returns a value and it is not a void action.